# Как в MenuStrip указать горячие клавиши (ShortcutKeys) так, чтобы они там там были чисто для вида, не блокируя события контролов?

Tags: c#, winforms

В результате установки свойства ShortcutKeys горячая клавиша перехватывается и обрабатывается событием Click пункта этого меню, но не доходит до контрола, которому она предназначалась.

```
var f = new Form();
var tb = new TextBox();
tb.Parent = f;
tb.Text = "test text";
var menu = new MenuStrip();
var item = new ToolStripMenuItem("test");
var item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("test");
item2.ShorcutKeys = Keys.Control | Keys.C;
item2.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("ctrl + c");
item.DropDownItems.Add(item2);
menu.Items.Add(item);
menu.Parent = f;
f.MainMenuStrip = menu;
f.ShowDialog();
```

Если попытаться скопировать строку из TextBox, вместо этого будет вызван Click пункта меню.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему. Желательно без наследования формы (если это возможно).

Comment: Что значит "не блокируя события"?

Comment: В результате установки свойства ShorcutKeys горячая клавиша перехватывается и обрабатывается событием Click пункта этого меню, но не доходит до контрола, которому она предназначалась.

Comment: Уже яснее, добавьте пожалуйста эту информацию в вопрос. Как выглядит обработчик события, который это перехватывает, или это встроенные средства контрола? А так же, покажите код. Укажите, как вы пытались решить эту задачу. И при чем тут наследование формы?

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Comment: А если в обработчике события ничего не делать или просто вызвать то что вам нужно явным образом? В `EventArgs` же можно проверить, что это было, клик мышкой или горячей клавиши? Или `sender` проверить, посмотреть, откуда собыите пришло.

Comment: Удаление обработчика Click ровным счётом ничего не меняет, контрол не получит горячую клавишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
item2.Enabled = false;
item.DropDownOpening += (sender, e) => item2.Enabled = true;
item.DropDownClosed += (sender, e) => item2.Enabled = false;
```